# How do you use the public access token with Unity webrequest?

Tags: c#, html, json, unity-game-engine, networking

I'm trying to get a JSON file from a website and I either get a 403 forbidden or a lot of HTML that doesn't include any useful data.

I might be doing it completely wrong because I have little to no understanding of `WebRequest`/networking and HTML.

```cs
public Text debugText;
public string websiteUrl;


IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    //UnityWebRequest.Get(uri)
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dictionary.Add("Authorization", "Bearer");

    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri))
    {

        webRequest.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer yQrAQWWxTZ2jyKg9vLOU ");

        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();

        string[] pages = uri.Split('/');
        int page = pages.Length - 1;

        Debug.Log("Headers: " + webRequest.GetResponseHeaders());

        if (webRequest.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {


            string jsonResult = webRequest.downloadHandler.text;
            Debug.Log(jsonResult);

            //Debug.Log(jsonResult);
            debugText.text = jsonResult;


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible you can use "PostMan" first to sure your post can be sccuess .

Comment: Are you sure your token should have a space on the end?

Comment: Can you share the website url?

Comment: @BugFinder no it wasn't but I fixed it already.

Comment: @barteezy The thing is I am not sure if I'm allowed to do that

Comment: From what you show (minus the extra space) theres no obvious reason this wont work unless the token needs to be newer than the hard coded one you have